# RequireJS - using module returns undefined

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm trying to use RequireJS in my app. I'm including the requirejs script from cdnjs like this:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.10/require.min.js"></script>
```

on my page I have a button and I register an event for it:

```
$('#btnSpeedTest').on('click', function (e) {
    require([baseUrl + 'Content/js/tools/speedtest.js'], function (speedTestModule) {
        alert(speedTestModule);
    });
});
```

If I watch with Fidler - I see that upon clicking the button speedtest.js is loaded.

speedtest.js contains the following:

```
define('speedTestModule', function () {
    function SpeedTest(settings, startNow) {
         // basic initialization
    }

    var fn = SpeedTest.prototype;

    fn.startRequest = function (download, twoRequests) {
         // logic
    }

    return SpeedTest;
});
```

The `alert(speedTestModule);` command returns "undefined". I saw a tutorial on RequireJS and in that tutorial everything was in the same directory as well as files with names of modules (which is not my case since I'm loading it from CDN).

I even tried to return a simple string, but it did not work. What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a named `define`. Instead of this:

```
define('speedTestModule', function () {
```

do this:

```
define(function () {
```

and let RequireJS name your module. You typically want to let `r.js` add names to your modules when you optimize them. There are a few cases where using names yourself in a `define` call is warranted but these are really special cases.